# Python Scripting Help - Add-on to auto swap materials working but with one flaw! Unrecognized materials given blank material slot

Tags: python, add-on

I need some help. I do not know how to code, though I’m starting to learn a bit. I have been using chat gpt to assist me in creating a custom tool as an add-on. I have gotten it to work most of the way but hit a wall.

We have made a digital library of products, all with many materials assigned to many many objects to use as assets. They were created at real to world scale using mostly procedural materials. We want to get back to standard blender scale, but the materials do not properly scale. So we created new materials of the same name at the proper scale. As we have hundreds of these I wanted to automate the swapping of the materials on these files. I’m almost there.

So far I have gotten it to

- successfully read materials from a specified .blend file as the new material library
- check the material names that match the names of the selected objects, while ignoring any suffixes like .001, .002, etc which happen when we add the same material to the scene more than once.
- Successfully swap the materials in the scene with the materials from the material path specified.

The problem comes when there is a material NOT in the specified material library. I want those to be ignored and left in place on the objects and only swap the materials recognized from the library file. However it is currently changing unrecognized materials into a blank slot.

I just want unrecognized materials to be ignored and left in place and the rest of the script to work as is. The robots couldn’t help. Can any one read the script and see what is going wrong? I appreciate your help!!!

Here is the script….

```
bl_info = {
  "name": "Swap Material Add-on",
  "author": "Dave Schwalbach",
  "version": (1, 0),
  "blender": (3, 0, 0),
  "description": "Swaps materials of selected objects from a library",
  "category": "Object",
}


class SwapMaterialFromFile(bpy.types.Operator):
  bl_idname = "object.swap_material_from_file"
  bl_label = "Swap Material from File"

  # Specific file path to the Blender file containing materials
  filepath: bpy.props.StringProperty(
    name="Swap Material File Path",
    description="Path to the Blender file containing materials",
    default="",
    maxlen=1024
  )

  @classmethod
  def poll(cls, context):
    return any(obj.type == 'MESH' for obj in context.view_layer.objects.selected)

  def execute(self, context):
    # Store the current scene
    current_scene = context.scene

    # Iterate through selected objects
    for obj in context.view_layer.objects.selected:
      for slot in obj.material_slots:
        # Check if the material is not None and not "Silver Label"
        if slot.material and slot.material.name != "Silver Label":
          try:
            # Check if the material name exists in the loaded file
            material_name = slot.material.name.split('.')[0] # Ignore suffixes

            # Load the material file
            with bpy.data.libraries.load(self.filepath) as (data_from, data_to):
              data_to.materials = [material_name]

            # Check if the material was recognized
            if data_to.materials:
              # Assign the material from the loaded file
              slot.material = data_to.materials[0]
              print(f"Swapped material: {material_name} in object: {obj.name}")
            else:
              # Print a warning if the material was not found
              print(f"Material not found in the loaded file: {material_name} in object: {obj.name}")

          except (IndexError, AttributeError) as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            # Handle IndexError (no materials in the loaded file) and AttributeError (material_name not found)
          except Exception as e:
            print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
            # Handle unexpected errors

    # Set the active scene back to the original scene
    context.window.scene = current_scene

    return {'FINISHED'}


# Panel definition with argument passing
class SwapMaterialPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
  bl_idname = "PANEL_PT_swap_material"
  bl_label = "Swap Material"
  bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
  bl_region_type = 'UI'
  bl_category = "Tool"

  # Define the filepath property within the class
  swap_material_from_file_filepath: bpy.props.StringProperty(
    name="Swap Material File Path",
    description="Path to the Blender file containing materials",
    default="X:\\AdvEng\\Industrial Design Documents\\Design Assets\\Blender Design Assets\\Asset Library\\Scaled Material Trial\\Materials Scaled Down Trial.blend",
    maxlen=1024
  )

  def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    # Use the filepath value in the label
    layout.label(text="Swap Material File: " + context.scene.swap_material_from_file_filepath, icon='INFO')

    # Add the "Execute" button
    layout.operator(SwapMaterialFromFile.bl_idname, text="Execute")


# Register add-on classes
def register():
  bpy.utils.register_class(SwapMaterialFromFile)
  bpy.utils.register_class(SwapMaterialPanel)

  # Register the property for the panel
  bpy.types.Scene.swap_material_from_file_filepath = bpy.props.StringProperty(
    name="Swap Material File Path",
    description="Temporary storage for file path during use.",
    default="",
    maxlen=1024
  )


def unregister():
  bpy.utils.unregister_class(SwapMaterialPanel)
  bpy.utils.unregister_class(SwapMaterialFromFile)

  # Unregister the property
  del bpy.types.Scene.swap_material_from_file_filepath


if __name__ == "__main__":
  register()
```

Please note, I have omitted the file path for privacy but is there in the script I am using.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

When there is no material with the name `material_name` `data_to.materials` contains `[None]` which is a truthy value such as `bool([None]) == True`

When you use `slot.material = [None][0]` which is `slot.material = None` you remove the material from the slot.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer. I will look into that this evening! Thank you!